# How to fix "Canceled future for execute_request message" error when using Polars?

Tags: python, python-polars

I'm using Polars to process a 35 GB file in Python, and I'm running the following line of code:

```
df.unique(subset=['id']).select(pl.count()).collect(streaming=True).item()
```

However, I'm getting the following error:

```
Canceled future for execute_request message before replies were done
The Kernel crashed while executing code in the the current cell or a previous cell. Please review the code in the cell(s) to identify a possible cause of the failure. Click here for more info. View Jupyter log for further details.
```

I believe this error is related to Polars lazy evaluation, but I'm not sure how to fix it. Can someone provide guidance on how to resolve this issue? Thank you in advance

update:
The version of Polars I am using is 0.16.6
Here is the Jupyter log:

```
  warn(
c:\Users\user\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\traitlets\traitlets.py:2495: FutureWarning: Supporting extra quotes around Bytes is deprecated in traitlets 5.0. Use '50d3e1a5-c144-464a-b1ed-5dc5d79b04f0' instead of 'b"50d3e1a5-c144-464a-b1ed-5dc5d79b04f0"'.
  warn(
memory allocation of 301430844 bytes failed

info 13:50:23.361: Dispose Kernel process 14504.
error 13:50:23.365: Raw kernel process exited code: 3221226505
error 13:50:23.412: Error in waiting for cell to complete [Error: Canceled future for execute_request message before replies were done
    at t.KernelShellFutureHandler.dispose (c:\Users\user\.vscode\extensions\ms-toolsai.jupyter-2023.2.1200692131\out\extension.node.js:2:33213)
    at c:\Users\user\.vscode\extensions\ms-toolsai.jupyter-2023.2.1200692131\out\extension.node.js:2:52265
    at Map.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at y._clearKernelState (c:\Users\user\.vscode\extensions\ms-toolsai.jupyter-2023.2.1200692131\out\extension.node.js:2:52250)
    at y.dispose (c:\Users\user\.vscode\extensions\ms-toolsai.jupyter-2023.2.1200692131\out\extension.node.js:2:45732)
    at c:\Users\user\.vscode\extensions\ms-toolsai.jupyter-2023.2.1200692131\out\extension.node.js:17:127079
    at ee (c:\Users\user\.vscode\extensions\ms-toolsai.jupyter-2023.2.1200692131\out\extension.node.js:2:1552543)
    at dh.dispose (c:\Users\user\.vscode\extensions\ms-toolsai.jupyter-2023.2.1200692131\out\extension.node.js:17:127055)
    at hh.dispose (c:\Users\user\.vscode\extensions\ms-toolsai.jupyter-2023.2.1200692131\out\extension.node.js:17:134354)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)]
warn 13:50:23.418: Cell completed with errors {
  message: 'Canceled future for execute_request message before replies were done'
}
info 13:50:23.433: Cancel all remaining cells true || Error || undefined
```

Comment: Is there any more info in the jupyter log? Can you try `df.select(pl.col("id").n_unique()).collect(streaming=True).item()`

Comment: @jqurious Thanks! you's suggestion work.